# ¿Cómo alineo mi texto? en html

Tags: html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo hace esta página para alinear el texto y para poner números grandes, e incluso alinearlos con fotos.
Quiero aprender a justificaa, a centrar, a poner el texto a la izquierda a la derecha, cualquier idea para que mi texto quede bien

Comment: Sé más especifico, agregaste 2 screenshots pero no señalas exactamente cuál texto. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/131729/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: quieor alinearlo tanto con fotografía, como sin fotografías de las dos maneras que están en las dos fotos

Comment: Edita la pregunta añadiendo esos detalles

Comment: Otros usuarios lo mencionaron antes en otras de tus preguntas: el código (en texto) vale más que mil imágenes. Esta pregunta es de muy baja calidad, no tiene una definición clara del problema y no se comparte nada de código en la propia pregunta. Ningún usuario debería tener que adivinar tu código o visitar un sitio externo para verlo. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita tu pregunta con las recomendaciones que encontrarás allí.

Answer (score 1):

Lo haces con el estilo `float: left;`. Puedes leer más sobre esta propiedad [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/float).
En el ejemplo además le agrego `margin: 10px;` para que el texto no quede pegado a la imagen.

```html
   <img class="imagen" width="200" src="https://cdn0.froala.com/assets/editor/pages/B/editor-photo-645d411798e5b4e825765d091dd5aaab.jpg" alt="Editor photo" style="float: left; margin: 10px;"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.</p>

    <p>sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
```

---

Las páginas de los ejemplos que pones hacen sus artículos con editores *wysiwyg (Lo que ves es lo que obtienes)*.

Para lo del número más grande, la idea es la misma del `float: left;`, sólo que en vez de una imagen, colocan un encabezado:`<h1>Ejemplo</h1>`

```html
<h2 style="float: left; margin: 10px;">1</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.</p>
```

Comment: Hola Andy Samuel, no todas las preguntas se pueden o deben contestar. Es mejor evitar responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos y que no se ajustan al contenido/formato del sitio. Lee [answer] para más información.